# Get data from Database through HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Im creating a function that will check if the username is already used. How can I get all the usernames in my database through HTTPUrlConnection? Should I use JSON?

Comment: why do you get all usernames? just send a request to check if the username exists in your database... you can do it in the server side without any huge effort.

Comment: I really have no idea with this can u give me an example?

Comment: Because that how I check in other languages, I put the value in a for loop. Its easy in php, but I'm new in Android Development thats why i really don't have an idea even with JSON. I tried many tutorials but no luck

Comment: Connect to your URL like this one: `myURL.com/myPhpScript.php?name=MyUsername` via HTTPUrlConnection, your php script checks if the username is taken and sends the answer to your app, then just read the InputStream